# Microsoft iSCSI Initiator potentially corrupted?

Tags: windows-11, iscsi

Let me start off by saying I'm pretty new and unexperienced with iSCSI. I'm on Windows 11 trying to get an iSCSI target connected to my laptop that is already connected to my desktop, so I know the target is good and functioning properly.

When I first open the Microsoft iSCSI initiator on my laptop I get an error stating:

```
The Microsoft iSCSI service is not running. The service is required to be started for iSCSI to function correctly. To start the service now and have the service start automatically each time the computer restarts, click the Yes button.
```

So I click Yes and after a while the initiator opens, but when I check in the windows 'services' app iSCSI is not listed as running. If I try to discover a portal I get a message saying that the `iSCSI initiator service is not running. Please start the service and retry.` So I tried manually starting the iSCSI service in the services app and adding the portal again. After a long while I get another error message saying `The remote procedure call was cancelled.`

It seems that no matter what I do I can't keep the iSCSI service running and I can't use the Microsoft iSCSI initiator. IS there any way to reinstall the initiator? Or any advice on how I can get it running would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually trying to connect the same iSCSI target to your desktop and your laptop at the same time? Although I don't think this is related to your problem with the iSCSI initiator, you should not do that.

Comment: Yea sounds like it's probably unrelated. But thanks for the info about multiple connections. Could I have two targets sharing the same extent then?